# Silverlight 5 DataGrid Merge Cells

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I need to merge cells across multiple rows. Something similar to a RowSpan on the cell. This is because I have two columns in the grid. Column 1 can have duplicate values that relate to the values in the column one. I want to merge values in the column 1 to just appear once for all the rows in column2.

Is there a way to achieve this on the DataGrid in Silverlight 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say this but most Silverlight grids do not support cell merging. At least not out of the box. I have resorted to using Component One studio for Silverlight in order to achieve this, and even then it hasn't been exactly a walk in the park.

Consider C1 Data Grid control. Here is a sample on [merging grid row and column headers](http://our.componentone.com/2012/01/27/styling-merged-column-row-header-cells-in-sl-datagrid/) with sample code and a small write up. The down side of such solutions is that C1's controls are extremely expensive :( I wish Microsoft came up with some enhancements in SL5 that would accommodate for such issues.